# R Function to get Confidence Interval of Difference Between Means

Tags: r, statistics, t-test

I am trying find a function that allows me two easily get the confidence interval of difference between two means.

I am pretty sure `t.test` has this functionality, but I haven't been able to make it work. Below is a screenshot of what I have tried so far:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HocQ0.png)

This is the dataset I am using

```
   Indoor Outdoor
1    0.07    0.29
2    0.08    0.68
3    0.09    0.47
4    0.12    0.54
5    0.12    0.97
6    0.12    0.35
7    0.13    0.49
8    0.14    0.84
9    0.15    0.86
10   0.15    0.28
11   0.17    0.32
12   0.17    0.32
13   0.18    1.55
14   0.18    0.66
15   0.18    0.29
16   0.18    0.21
17   0.19    1.02
18   0.20    1.59
19   0.22    0.90
20   0.22    0.52
21   0.23    0.12
22   0.23    0.54
23   0.25    0.88
24   0.26    0.49
25   0.28    1.24
26   0.28    0.48
27   0.29    0.27
28   0.34    0.37
29   0.39    1.26
30   0.40    0.70
31   0.45    0.76
32   0.54    0.99
33   0.62    0.36
```

and I have been trying to use `t.test` function that has been installed from

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
```

I am pretty new to R, so sorry if there is a simple answer to this question. I have searched around quite a bit and haven't been able to find anything that I am looking for.

Note: The output I am looking for is Between -1.224 and 0.376

Edit:

The CI of difference between means I am looking for is if a random 34th datapoint was added to the chart by picking a random value in the Indoor column and a random value in the Outdoor column and duplicating it. Running the `t.test` will output the correct CI for the difference of means for the given sample size of 33.

How can I go about doing this pretending the sample size is 34?

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example, and example output? Images of code is not a good idea.

Comment: @AkselA updated with the data set and the function I've been trying to use

Comment: Why do you expect a CI of [-1.224, 0.376]?

Comment: @AkselA I apologize, I did not provide nearly enough context in this question. I made an edit to the bottom. I am expecting a CI of [-1.224, 0.376] because this is part of a homework assignment and I have the answer key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's probably something more convenient in the standard library, but it's pretty easy to calculate.  given your `df` variable, we can just do:

```r
# calculate mean of difference
d_mu <- mean(df$Indoor) - mean(df$Outdoor)
# calculate SD of difference
d_sd <- sqrt(var(df$Indoor) + var(df$Outdoor))

# calculate 95% CI of this
d_mu + d_sd * qt(c(0.025, 0.975), nrow(df)*2)
```

giving me: `-1.2246 0.3767`

mostly for @AkselA: I often find it helpful to check my work by sampling simpler distributions, in this case I'd do something like:

```r
a <- mean(df$Indoor) + sd(df$Indoor) * rt(1000000, nrow(df)-1)
b <- mean(df$Outdoor) + sd(df$Outdoor) * rt(1000000, nrow(df)-1)
quantile(a - b, c(0.025, 0.975))
```

which gives me answers much closer to the CI I gave in the comment

Comment: Thank you! Like I said, I am very new to R so even simple calculations like this are not easy for me. This helped a lot

Comment: I should note that this might be wrong!  I added the `*2` to the degrees of freedom to match your "known good" answer.  I think this should probably be removed, and the actual CI should be (-1.240, 0.392)

Comment: `2*nrow(df) - 2` should give you the correct degrees of freedom, as you're pooling the standard deviations.

Comment: @AkselA thanks, you're right I forgot the `-1`. I don't think the SDs are being pooled here, so the DoF are therefore the minimum of the DoF of both sides.  this would be `nrow(df)-1`

Answer (score 1):

Even though I always find the approach of manually calculating the results, as shown by @Sam Mason, the most insightful, there are some who want a shortcut. And sometimes, it's also ok to be lazy :)

So among the different ways to calculate CIs, this is imho the most comfortable:

```
DescTools::MeanDiffCI(Indoor, Outdoor)
```

Here's a reprex:

```
IV <- diamonds$price
DV <- rnorm(length(IV), mean = mean(IV), sd = sd(IV))
DescTools::MeanDiffCI(IV, DV)
```

gives

```
 meandiff    lwr.ci    upr.ci 
-18.94825 -66.51845  28.62195
```

This is calculated with 999 bootstrapped samples by default. If you want 1000 or more, you can just add that in the argument `R`:

```
DescTools::MeanDiffCI(IV, DV, R = 1000)
```